# How to find responses from an event of icalendar? PHP

Tags: php, icalendar

Does anyone know how to access to people's responses for an icalendar event? And also i can see the buttons (Yes/No/Maybe) but i couldnt click them. Dont unerstand how to manage. Some resourse or answers would be so good.
 Thanks.

```
$cal_uid = date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."-".rand()."@mydomain.com";


    $mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".md5(time());
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";  
    $headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";


    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
    $headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";


    $message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";

    $message .= "<html>\n";
    $message .= "<body>\n";
    $message .= '<p>Merhaba '.$firstname.' '.$lastname.',</p>'; 
    $message .= $message1;    
    $message .= "</body>\n";
    $message .= "</html>\n";

    $message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";


$ical =    'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REPLY
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:'.$from_address.'
DTSTART:'.$dtstart.'
DTEND:'.$dtend.'
LOCATION:'.$meeting_location.'
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
UID:'.$cal_uid.'
DTSTAMP:'.$todaystamp.'
DESCRIPTION:'.$meeting_description.'
SUMMARY:'.$subject.'
PRIORITY:5
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN='.$firstname.':MAILTO:'.$email.'
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR';   

    $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST;charset=utf-8\n';
    $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST\n';
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
    $message .= $ical;            

    //SEND MAIL
    $mail_sent = @mail( $email, $subject, $message, $headers );
```